# Adding a column to a dataframe (SQL or Python, no preference) by comparing values in the current row to each prior row

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to add a column to. Here's the example dataframe:

| Student Name | HW submission time stamp | Computer error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2023-07-08T18:38:56.875 | 0 |
| John | 2023-07-11T22:09:02.509 | 1 |
| John | 2023-07-11T22:11:35.022 | 1 |
| John | 2023-08-26T20:42:15.201 | 1 |

The column I want to create is Number_of_Computer_Errors_in_last_day where each row has a value representing how many times there was a computer error in the past day in previous rows.

I tried to use a window function but it's so wrong that I don't think it will be helpful to provide it here.

The output that I'm expecting is:

| Student Name | HW submission time stamp | Computer error | Num_Computer_Err_in_Past_Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2023-07-08T18:38:56.875 | 0 | 0 |
| John | 2023-07-11T22:09:02.509 | 1 | 0 |
| John | 2023-07-11T22:11:35.022 | 1 | 1 |
| John | 2023-08-26T20:42:15.201 | 1 | 0 |

Only the third row should have any value here because there was a computer error only a few hours earlier in the second row, but I want to create code that checks all rows that come before it. I'm very stuck and any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I was talking to a friend and they recommended that I join the table to itself. You can do a left join to itself to retain all of the students to generalize the problem and then you calculate the time frame you're interested in.

`SELECT student_name,
t1.hw_ts, count(*)

FROM (SELECT student name, t1.hw_ts FROM table) as t1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_name, hw_ts FROM table t2) as t2

ON t1.student_name == t2.student_name and t2.hw_ts < t1.hw_ts and t2.hw_ts > t1.hw_ts - 24 hours) group by 1, 2`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).